# Google analytics custom dimensions jquery or web api

Tags: jquery, html, google-analytics, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to add Google analytics in static website (only html pages) where basic authentication used. It all works good but I couldn't able to enable the custom dimensions to view unique user report as I wont be able to get the username from basic authentication in html page. Is there anyway I can get the username using jquery or can I use web api, pass the header to api and extract the username pass it back to html?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in javascript to retrive the username that was authenticated (using basic-auth).

The only way you can do so is to use some serverside language to add that username into your code (set variable in javascript that contains the authenticated user).